# How to maintain line breaks within a 2013 multi-line task field after datasheet edit

Tags: 2013, datasheet, multiline-text-field

We use datasheets to edit multi-line task lists. Since being migrated to SharePoint 2013 the new datasheet view doesn't allow us to maintain line breaks after we stop editing the datasheet.

Can anyone tell me how to maintain line-breaks, please?

**What we enter**

> Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum.
>
> Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum.

**What it looks like when we stop editing the datasheet**

> Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this in a 2013 task list. Is it a 2010 version of the task list or earlier versions?

Comment: Same as user19952. I create a new task list, add it a new multiline field and try with your example, the result was a text with a break line.

Comment: Thats true, I am able to maintain line breaks on my multi line plain text field in a custom list.

Comment: What is the css white space property on that element? Maybe change that white-space: pre-line; ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Datasheet view uses the Data Connectivity Components, similar to MS Access, you can use the keyboard to force a line break by pressing [ALT]+[ENTER] to place a line break character into the datasheet cell.